# Can I calculate modulus of large number by taking modulus of each digit and taking sum?

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers, modulo, number-theory

The problem is, I got all digits of a very large number, I need to find whether it is divisible by 3. I tried my approach which I suppose is wrong but I don't know why

This is my approach
for example problem is (159%3)

I could write it as (100+50+9)%3
the above statement can be written as (1%3+5%3+9%3)%3
by `(a+b)%c=(a%c+b%c)%c`.

What is wrong in this approach?

Comment: Are all the digits in order? Do you know what the number is, or just its digits (out of order)?

Comment: It is in order.

Comment: @JohnFilleau It doesn't matter if the digits are in order or not.

Comment: @tele my god you're right. My 4th grade teacher would be disappointed in me :(

Comment: After being schooled, it turns out your approach is fine. Why do you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: This approach is correct. You are using the fact that 10^n % 3 = 1. What is your problem exactly with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for divisibility by `3`, you only need to check if a number's digits sum to a number that is divisible by `3`. For example, 159 is divisible by 3 because `1+5+9 = 15`, which is divisible by three.

Note that this approach *only works for 3 and 9*, so don't try using this for other modulos!

Comment: But there are a bunch of similar things for various divisors. Divisible by 2: last digit is divisible by 2. Divisible by 4: value represented by last 2 digits is divisible by 4. Divisible by 5: last digit is 0 or 5. Divisible by 6: divisible by 3 and divisible by 2. Divisible by 8: value represented by last 3 digits is divisible by 8. Remainders for all those divisors follow trivially from the divisibility observations. Divisible by 7 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Another simple one: Divisible by 11: sum of digits in even positions (counting from the right) is equal to sum of digits in odd positions.